# contact form 7 not redirect. When I click the submit it added #wpcf7-f1415-p1406-o1 in url

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have contact form 7 in my website I tried to redirect

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you/';"
```

but its not working. instead of redirect it add the "**#wpcf7-f1415-p1406-o1**" end of url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some information by Wordpress Community**,

Solution #1 (Deprecated): Simply put this code in the “Additional Settings” area of the Contact form 7 Admin:

on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/thank-you/';"
Solution #1 was the recommended solution until recently for Redirecting to a Thank You Page, but the Contact Form 7 developer has stated that the method of using on_sent_ok hook is no longer recommended. Don’t ask me why he would do such a thing, but the function is scheduled to be abolished by the end of 2017.

So, you can try to implement another way to contact form redirect on thank you page.

```html
Code:
//This function prints the JavaScript to the footer
function add_this_script_footer(){ ?>
 
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = 'http://yourdomain.com/thank-you';
}, false );
</script>
 
<?php } 
 
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this_script_footer');
```

Get the More Info. So, you can go through this link,

[Redirect to a Thank You Page with WordPress Contact Form 7](http://sharewebdesign.com/blog/redirect-to-a-thank-you-page-with-wordpress-contact-form-7/)